# record-builder: TypeElement.getRecordComponents() returns duplicated record component (one without accessor)

Tags: java, annotations, java-17, java-annotations, java-record

While trying to troubleshoot & fix [this issue](https://github.com/Randgalt/record-builder/issues/139) from record-builder (a Java annotation processor), I observed that `TypeElement.getRecordComponents()` returns two entries for the same record component. I'm trying to understand if this behavior is expected from the JDK or a bug.

record-builder has a feature allowing you to generate a record from an interface. Following interface definition

```java
@RecordInterface
interface Conf {

    int maxConcurrency( );
}
```

generates following code

```java
@Generated("io.soabase.recordbuilder.core.RecordInterface")
@RecordBuilder
public record ConfRecord(int maxConcurrency) implements Conf, ConfRecordBuilder.With {}
```

I was able to observe that when `ConfRecord` class file already exists on disk; `TypeElement.getRecordComponents()` returns two `maxConcurrency` entries. One with (name: maxConcurrency, pos: 1, accessor: null), and another one with (name: maxConcurrency, pos: 387, accessor: <value>)

The first entry is set from `setRecordComponents` when existing class file is parsed (triggered by an import statement).

```
setRecordComponents:1542, Symbol$ClassSymbol (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
read:1224, ClassReader$26 (com.sun.tools.javac.jvm)
readAttrs:1373, ClassReader (com.sun.tools.javac.jvm)
readClassAttrs:1387, ClassReader (com.sun.tools.javac.jvm)
readClass:2527, ClassReader (com.sun.tools.javac.jvm)
readClassBuffer:2644, ClassReader (com.sun.tools.javac.jvm)
readClassFile:2658, ClassReader (com.sun.tools.javac.jvm)
fillIn:361, ClassFinder (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
complete:291, ClassFinder (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
complete:-1, ClassFinder$$Lambda$95/0x0000000801254af8 (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
complete:682, Symbol (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
complete:1410, Symbol$ClassSymbol (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
loadClass:434, ClassFinder (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
loadClass:2052, Resolve (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
findIdentInPackageInternal:2450, Resolve (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
findIdentInPackage:2438, Resolve (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
selectSym:4412, Attr (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
visitSelect:4297, Attr (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
accept:2450, JCTree$JCFieldAccess (com.sun.tools.javac.tree)
attribTree:677, Attr (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
attribType:743, Attr (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
attribType:736, Attr (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
attribImportType:447, TypeEnter$ImportsPhase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
doImport:430, TypeEnter$ImportsPhase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
resolveImports:370, TypeEnter$ImportsPhase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
runPhase:327, TypeEnter$ImportsPhase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
doCompleteEnvs:288, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
completeEnvs:257, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
complete:204, TypeEnter (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
complete:682, Symbol (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
complete:1410, Symbol$ClassSymbol (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
flags:1331, Symbol$ClassSymbol (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
isAccessible:327, Resolve (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
isAccessible:310, Resolve (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
loadClass:2053, Resolve (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
findGlobalType:2299, Resolve (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
findType:2373, Resolve (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
findIdentInternal:2416, Resolve (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
findIdent:2402, Resolve (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
resolveIdent:2685, Resolve (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
visitIdent:4184, Attr (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
accept:2584, JCTree$JCIdent (com.sun.tools.javac.tree)
attribTree:677, Attr (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
attribType:743, Attr (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
attribType:736, Attr (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
signature:116, MemberEnter (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
visitMethodDef:193, MemberEnter (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
accept:921, JCTree$JCMethodDecl (com.sun.tools.javac.tree)
memberEnter:163, MemberEnter (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
memberEnter:175, MemberEnter (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
finishClass:1075, TypeEnter$MembersPhase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
runPhase:1019, TypeEnter$MembersPhase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
doCompleteEnvs:288, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
doCompleteEnvs:928, TypeEnter$AbstractMembersPhase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
completeEnvs:257, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
completeEnvs:272, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
completeEnvs:272, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
completeEnvs:272, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
completeEnvs:272, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
completeEnvs:272, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
complete:204, TypeEnter (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
complete:682, Symbol (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
complete:1410, Symbol$ClassSymbol (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
complete:610, Enter (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
main:587, Enter (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
enterTrees:1042, JavaCompiler (com.sun.tools.javac.main)
compile:917, JavaCompiler (com.sun.tools.javac.main)
lambda$doCall$0:104, JavacTaskImpl (com.sun.tools.javac.api)
call:-1, JavacTaskImpl$$Lambda$89/0x00000008012368e0 (com.sun.tools.javac.api)
invocationHelper:152, JavacTaskImpl (com.sun.tools.javac.api)
doCall:100, JavacTaskImpl (com.sun.tools.javac.api)
call:94, JavacTaskImpl (com.sun.tools.javac.api)
compileInProcess:136, JavaxToolsCompiler (org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac)
performCompile:182, JavacCompiler (org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac)
execute:1209, AbstractCompilerMojo (org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler)
execute:198, CompilerMojo (org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler)
executeMojo:137, DefaultBuildPluginManager (org.apache.maven.plugin)
doExecute2:370, MojoExecutor (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
doExecute:351, MojoExecutor (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
execute:215, MojoExecutor (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
execute:171, MojoExecutor (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
execute:163, MojoExecutor (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
buildProject:117, LifecycleModuleBuilder (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
buildProject:81, LifecycleModuleBuilder (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
build:56, SingleThreadedBuilder (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded)
execute:128, LifecycleStarter (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
doExecute:294, DefaultMaven (org.apache.maven)
doExecute:192, DefaultMaven (org.apache.maven)
execute:105, DefaultMaven (org.apache.maven)
execute:960, MavenCli (org.apache.maven.cli)
doMain:293, MavenCli (org.apache.maven.cli)
main:196, MavenCli (org.apache.maven.cli)
invoke0:-1, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:77, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:43, DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:568, Method (java.lang.reflect)
launchEnhanced:282, Launcher (org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher)
launch:225, Launcher (org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher)
mainWithExitCode:406, Launcher (org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher)
main:347, Launcher (org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher)
```

The second one is set by the annotation processor while reading generated code

```
getRecordComponent:1524, Symbol$ClassSymbol (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
runPhase:968, TypeEnter$RecordPhase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
doCompleteEnvs:288, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
doCompleteEnvs:928, TypeEnter$AbstractMembersPhase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
completeEnvs:257, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
completeEnvs:272, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
completeEnvs:272, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
completeEnvs:272, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
completeEnvs:272, TypeEnter$Phase (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
complete:204, TypeEnter (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
complete:682, Symbol (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
complete:1410, Symbol$ClassSymbol (com.sun.tools.javac.code)
complete:610, Enter (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
main:587, Enter (com.sun.tools.javac.comp)
enterTrees:1042, JavaCompiler (com.sun.tools.javac.main)
enterTrees:1247, JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round (com.sun.tools.javac.processing)
<init>:1133, JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round (com.sun.tools.javac.processing)
next:1153, JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round (com.sun.tools.javac.processing)
doProcessing:1393, JavacProcessingEnvironment (com.sun.tools.javac.processing)
processAnnotations:1234, JavaCompiler (com.sun.tools.javac.main)
compile:916, JavaCompiler (com.sun.tools.javac.main)
lambda$doCall$0:104, JavacTaskImpl (com.sun.tools.javac.api)
call:-1, JavacTaskImpl$$Lambda$89/0x00000008012368e0 (com.sun.tools.javac.api)
invocationHelper:152, JavacTaskImpl (com.sun.tools.javac.api)
doCall:100, JavacTaskImpl (com.sun.tools.javac.api)
call:94, JavacTaskImpl (com.sun.tools.javac.api)
compileInProcess:136, JavaxToolsCompiler (org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac)
performCompile:182, JavacCompiler (org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac)
execute:1209, AbstractCompilerMojo (org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler)
execute:198, CompilerMojo (org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler)
executeMojo:137, DefaultBuildPluginManager (org.apache.maven.plugin)
doExecute2:370, MojoExecutor (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
doExecute:351, MojoExecutor (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
execute:215, MojoExecutor (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
execute:171, MojoExecutor (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
execute:163, MojoExecutor (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
buildProject:117, LifecycleModuleBuilder (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
buildProject:81, LifecycleModuleBuilder (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
build:56, SingleThreadedBuilder (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded)
execute:128, LifecycleStarter (org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal)
doExecute:294, DefaultMaven (org.apache.maven)
doExecute:192, DefaultMaven (org.apache.maven)
execute:105, DefaultMaven (org.apache.maven)
execute:960, MavenCli (org.apache.maven.cli)
doMain:293, MavenCli (org.apache.maven.cli)
main:196, MavenCli (org.apache.maven.cli)
invoke0:-1, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:77, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:43, DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:568, Method (java.lang.reflect)
launchEnhanced:282, Launcher (org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher)
launch:225, Launcher (org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher)
mainWithExitCode:406, Launcher (org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher)
main:347, Launcher (org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher)
```

`Symbol#getRecordCompoment` has some logic to avoid duplicate components

```java
       public RecordComponent getRecordComponent(JCVariableDecl var, boolean addIfMissing, List<JCAnnotation> annotations) {
            RecordComponent toRemove = null;
            for (RecordComponent rc : recordComponents) {
                /* it could be that a record erroneously declares two record components with the same name, in that
                 * case we need to use the position to disambiguate
                 */
                if (rc.name == var.name && var.pos == rc.pos) {
                    if (rc.type.hasTag(TypeTag.ERROR) && !var.sym.type.hasTag(TypeTag.ERROR)) {
                        // Found a record component with an erroneous type: save it so that it can be removed later.
                        // If the class type of the record component is generated by annotation processor, it should
                        // use the new actual class type and symbol instead of the old dummy ErrorType.
                        toRemove = rc;
                    } else {
                        // Found a good record component: just return.
                        return rc;
                    }
                }
            }
            RecordComponent rc = null;
            if (toRemove != null) {
                // Found a record component with an erroneous type: remove it and create a new one
                recordComponents = List.filter(recordComponents, toRemove);
                recordComponents = recordComponents.append(rc = new RecordComponent(var.sym, annotations));
            } else if (addIfMissing) {
                // Didn't find the record component: create one.
                recordComponents = recordComponents.append(rc = new RecordComponent(var.sym, annotations));
            }
            return rc;
        }
```

We can see that de-duplication is done by name AND position. However, position reported from class file and source parsing differs; leading to two entries. And even more bizarre, a record component with a null accessor.

1. Is it expected that `TypeElement#getRecordComponents` returns two record component entries for the same record component?
2. Is it expected that `RecordComponent#getAccessor` returns null?
3. Is it a JDK bug or should the annotation processor ignore RecordComponents with no accessor?

Notes:

- TypeElement's Javadoc is unclear to me.
- Java 17.0.5, 19.0.2, 21.ea.7 behave the same way.
- I think it is related to the interface defining what is an accessor to the record. Running `javap -v` on the record shows `Record:\n  int maxConcurrency; \n\ndescriptor: I`
- Providing a reproducer is doable but requires some efforts. I think that knowlegeable persons are unlikely to require a working repoducer to explain the behavior.

Update 1: Published a reproducer here: https://github.com/cykl/record-builder-139-reproducer

Comment: Thanks @brian-goetz. I did not mention record-builder in the title because unless I'm mistaken, all code paths leading to observed behavior are in JDK and could be reproduced without record-builder.

Comment: Sounds like there might be a bug (or two) in the JDK’s code. But what I don’t understand: the record is built by this record-builder from the annotated interface. So it knows the record components even before the source code has been generated. Why does it require the compiler feedback from the generated source code at all? That’s almost as weird as a compiler that parses its generated class files to find out what it has generated…

Comment: I'm still looking for a minimal reproducer. My current understanding is that issue doesn't occurs on fresh builds. It seems to occur after an initial build created ConfRecord source and class files and a file including ConfRecord is modified. I guess javac first parses the class from previous build (stacktrace #1), then annotation processor parses the source file (stacktrace #2). It's unclear to me if this is expected.

Comment: @Holger I just updated the question to add a link to a reproducer. Any insight from someone more knowledgeable than me on this topic would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Author of RecordBuilder here... I've been able to reproduce this in IntelliJ by compiling a single class. There seems to be a bug in javac with processing an annotated class generated by an annotation processor, though the docs say this should work. I have yet to refine it further however.

Comment: Further down the rabbit hole... in my case, the existence of a .class file of the generated record in the output path causes the problem. If I delete it prior to generating the record the exception doesn't happen.

Comment: Update from 2024... I modified Record-Builder to manually create the record instead of relying on another annotation round. This solves the first problem only to expose another problem.  "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$MethodSymbol.flags()" because "rc.accessor" is null" - I've posted a bug in the JDK bug DB. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯